# ParseException when trying to concatenate a string containing HTML in Hive query

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to concatenate two strings in Hive like below, but it keeps complaining about a ParseException

```
select concat('<a href="', 'https://www.nytimes.com/pages/', cast(77 as varchar), '">', cast(77 as varchar), '</a>') as page_url
;
```

The message says:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:13 cannot recognize input near 'concat' '(' ''<a href="'' in expression specification
```

I tried using backticks around the strings and also escaping any potential special characters, but no luck. How can I get the concatenation to work?

I'm using Hive version 2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the problem was arising because I was using cast as `varchar` when I should have been using `string`